# After updating the system to 14.04, an application fails due to lack of libpng15. How do i obtain it?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, 14.04, dependencies, libraries

After updating my Kubuntu to 14.04, one of applications (the "King Arthur's Gold" indie game) would fail due to lack of libpng15 in the system.

The error message is:

```
[13:47:13] PNG warning: Application was compiled with png.h from libpng-1.5.5
[13:47:13] PNG warning: Application  is  running with png.c from libpng-1.2.50
[13:47:13] PNG fatal error: Incompatible libpng version in application and library
[13:47:13] LOAD PNG: Internal PNG create read struct failure
```

I've searched the packages and only found `libpng12-0`. I've also googled for `libpng15` and faild to find any PPAs or something.

I've also tried to follow this [piece of advice](https://forum.kag2d.com/threads/segmentation-fault-on-start-on-fedora-20-heisenbug-and-ubuntu-14-04-trusty.18149/):

> Just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty). Unfortunately it has no libpng15 in standard repositories. I've found source code of library at here, built it with usual way (`./configure && make`). I didn't want to install it globally so I copied shared library (in my case it was in `<libpng_build_dir>/.libs/libpng15.so`) to KAG directory. After that game is runnable with `LD_PRELOAD=./libpng15.so ./rungame`

I've tried that and failed. The program would still claim that it runs with `libpng-1.2.50`.

`libpng15.so` is located in the application folder, it weighs 694454 bytes, is owned by current user and has `-rwxrwxr-x` permissions.

**UPD1:** `ldd ./KAG  | grep png` shows:

```
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xf7122000)
```